# Why won`t my bootstrap site show right on iPad and mobil device. It won`t fall back into center position after touch to the left side

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build my first website with bootstrap. However, when I view it on iPad and Mobil device. And I touch slide the webpage to the left side of the screen, it will not fall back to center position. However, when sliding to the right side if falls back to center as it should.

I should also say, i don`t use any bootstrap media queries. dont know how yet.

I made a picture to illustrated the problem
[picture link](http://i61.tinypic.com/2nvtttx.png)

[Link to my website](https://873c080e288ca6c13b309b6574effb96f7198285.googledrive.com/host/0B1wzdGzsm7UaflNBdWhybXQ4YmNBNDhkbXV1NXJ2VXFEdkZ2QzNZbEdHVVpNcURsc3piY1k/)

Kind Regards

Thomas

Comment: I can't replicate any of the problems you mention by viewing your site.  Please post some code and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) - in the future your links won't be visible and this post won't be useful to someone with a similar issue.  I'm unable to view your picture link from my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because of your line class, width: 1140px. it should bee 100% or auto depending on what you want

Comment: yes but i dont know what i am looking for. or what this error is called, i use chrome inspector all the time, a great tool

Comment: how do i close the post now?

Comment: You don't close it, you choose this as the accepted answer if it worked for you. Make sure to read more about how the site works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hi Alec thanks for the help i set the line width to 100%. and it works thanks :) –